# Extract subpatterns from regex_match result

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, pattern-matching

While executing this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string s("abcd");
    smatch m;
    regex rgx("a(b(.+))");
    if(regex_match(s,m,rgx))
        for(const auto& sub : m)
            cout<<sub.str()<<endl;
}
```

... I expect:

```
abcd
bcd
cd
```

... but I get:

```
abcd
abcd
bcd
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fc9d3e08105afcd)

Comment: So this must be a bug in my compiler (gcc 4.8.3).

Comment: It's not the compiler, it's the version of the std library you are using. Try with -stdlib=libc++ rather than the default -stdlib=libstdc++. Better yet, switch to clang which uses libc++ by default.